# Angular 2 RC5 update zone issue

Tags: angular

> zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: TypeError: Cannot read
>   property 'type' of null
>   at eval
>   (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13673:45)
>         at Array.forEach (native)
>         at getTransitiveModules (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13672:17)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver._getTransitiveNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13387:37)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13259:47)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:51)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:41)
>         at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:25)
>         at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:29)
>         at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:25)
>     Evaluating http://localhost:4565/dist/main.js   Error loading
>   http://localhost:4565/dist/main.js ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then
>   ; Value: Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null
>         at eval (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13673:45)
>         at Array.forEach (native)
>         at getTransitiveModules (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13672:17)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver._getTransitiveNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13387:37)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13259:47)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:51)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:41)
>         at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:25)
>         at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:29)
>         at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:25)
>     Evaluating http://localhost:4565/dist/main.js   Error loading
>   http://localhost:4565/dist/main.jsconsoleError @ zone.js:461_loop_1 @
>   zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @
>   zone.js:426 zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error:
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of null(…)consoleError @
>   zone.js:463_loop_1 @ zone.js:490drainMicroTaskQueue @
>   zone.js:494ZoneTask.invoke @ zone.js:426

Can anyone help me with this update error ? I don't understand it it comes from a wrong import ?

> zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: TypeError: Cannot
>   read property 'type' of null
>         at eval (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13673:45)
>         at Array.forEach (native)
>         at getTransitiveModules (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13672:17)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver._getTransitiveNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13387:37)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13259:47)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:51)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:41)
>         at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:25)
>         at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:29)
>         at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:25)
>     Evaluating http://localhost:4565/dist/main.js   Error loading
>   http://localhost:4565/dist/main.js
>         at eval (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13673:45)
>         at Array.forEach (native)
>         at getTransitiveModules (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13672:17)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver._getTransitiveNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13387:37)
>         at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:13259:47)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15845:51)
>         at RuntimeCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15769:41)
>         at RuntimeCompiler.compileModuleAsync (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/compiler//bundles/compiler.umd.js:15746:25)
>         at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9991:29)
>         at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/@angular/core//bundles/core.umd.js:9984:25)
>     Evaluating http://localhost:4565/dist/main.js   Error loading
>   http://localhost:4565/dist/main.js
>       at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:538:32)
>       at resolvePromise (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:523:18)
>       at http://localhost:4565/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:18
>       at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:38)
>       at Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:48)
>       at drainMicroTaskQueue (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:36)
>       at XMLHttpRequest.ZoneTask.invoke (http://localhost:4565/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22)

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code causing this. Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Answer (score 0):

Can't say clearly without seeing the code.

But there are a few breaking changes in rc5.

Read this article.
https://www.barbarianmeetscoding.com/blog/2016/08/13/updating-your-angular-2-app-from-rc4-to-rc5-a-practical-guide/

Other than that there are a few errors that come up in spec js.